# Human body parts in a cocktail?

Tags: ingredients, cocktails, drink

Human body parts in a cocktail?

It is a question that seems to come out of *[The Twilight Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone)*.

Up in the Yukon (Canada) there existed (exists) a cocktail made with a real severed human toe called [The Sour Toe Cocktail](https://www.cbc.ca/shortdocs/blog/the-story-of-the-sourtoe-cocktail-a-shot-of-whiskey-garnished-with-a-human).

It's like a Halloween cocktail just came to life and a sordid life at that!

My question is: **Do other drinks or cocktails exist or have existed with other real human body parts?**

Comment: Seriously?!  Ken you always struck me as being one of the more sane members here - blimey, have you gone to the 'dark side'?!!!!! (Joking)

Comment: @dougal5.0.0 You have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you count [Body Shots](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=body%20shot), then it would seem the answer to this question is a firm **no**.

But, there are cases of body parts being used in cocktails - fortunately, of other animal species. [This article](https://vinepair.com/wine-blog/9-bizarro-cocktail-garnishes/) references an octopus tentacle used as a garnish, as well as another that uses Sea Urchin gonads... The article also references the Sour Toe cocktail.

I have also heard of using rooster feathers as a garnish to make a "Cock's Tail cocktail" but, I can't find a reference to that anywhere... Finally, [this article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/foodanddrinknews/11411240/Would-you-drink-a-pigs-blood-cocktail.html) details a pig's blood cocktail made in the UK.

It seems that, for now, the Sour Toe is a one-of-a-kind... Honestly, I myself would prefer that things stay this way (barf ;)